# Scala "does not take parameters" when pattern-matching parametric case-class

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
sealed trait A

case class B[T](v: T) extends A
case class C[T](v: T) extends A

object Test {
  def swap(a: A): A = a match {
    case a: B[t] => C[t](a.v) // works!
    case C[t](v) => B[t](v) // error: C[t] does not take parameters
  }
}
```

I would expect either both cases to fail or both of them to work. What's the meaning of the error for the second case? Is there a syntax destructuring parametric case-classes?

Note: Here, 't' in lower case is essential. If it were 'T', the checker would be looking for it in the type parameters of the method.

Comment: This is also the case when doing extracting for vals, i.e. `val C[T](v) = ...`

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding your code ... you using `t` to represent a type? When by convention types are represented with an initial uppercase letter? And, to confuse things further, you are using the parameter `v` to hold the value for the argument `v`? Please make your code a little less ... self-referential.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: Using a capital letter for the type would cause an error here, and using binding `v` to `a.v` doesn't seem so terrible to me.

Comment: I see your point, Travis Brown. My experience is that if you get an error message about `v`, is it about the argument or the parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `a match { case C(v) => ??? }`, you actually call `unapply` method of the `C` companion object, something like this: `C.unapply(a) match {Some(v) => ???}`

There is only one `C` object, not an entire family of `C[t]`. There is no object you can refer to as `C[Int]`, so `case C[t](v) =>` doesn't make sense.

In your example, you use `B[t]` as a type, not as a pattern, and that's why it works. Note that while the match may succeed, you won't get anything in `t`, because of type erasure.

When you call `C[t](a.v)`, then first of all, compiler erases type `t` anyway, and second, this is rewritten to a call to `apply` method on the companion object: `C.apply[t](a.v)`. Note that the type parameter is on the method call, not on the object.

Comment: The two answers complement each other - this is more detailed, but is a little bit unclear on the erasure and "why" B[t] works that way. The other one explains with an actual reference the behavior (in the reference, there are examples which illustrate and explain exactly what happens with respect to type erasure. Which of the two answers should I accept?

Comment: The more detailed/popular one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it is not part of the language.

When used in this position, the compiler is looking for the type in the environment, as if it were a usual uppercase type. The type capturing that you are trying to do seems to only work in the `case x:Y[z] => ...` form of a case statement.

Type capturing in this fashion is not a well know part of the language and had me running to the [Scala reference document](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) for the details (Section 8.3). I personally find the that the distinction between upper and lowercase here not to my liking.

In your example `t` takes on the type of `Any` as the type information for the parameter is not available from `A`.